# cv2.findContours recognising arbitrary contours

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, contour

I am trying to identify numbers in images. I am using the cv2.findContours function to "separate" the digits in the photo. But even after several modifications to the image the function recognises arbitrary contours even in the absolute top left corner of the image even though the final modified image has an absolutely black background with only the digits being white. Why is it so? Complete source code along with photo and everything else :
https://github.com/tanmay-edgelord/HandwrittenDigitRecognition
Source code : 
https://github.com/tanmay-edgelord/HandwrittenDigitRecognition/blob/master/performRecognition.ipynb

In this code I am using the `rects = [cv2.boundingRect(ctr) for ctr in ctrs]` line to identify the contours returned by the function. Upon printing it out I found out that many of the bounding rectangles are in (0,0,0,0). If any further details/clarification is required please comment.

Comment: Please post a sample image of the results. You can use `cv2.drawContours` to display the contour results. Post before and after images

Comment: Issue solved. Apparently I was using the old openCV syntax to recieve the return values from findContours() function. I did not know that they changed it with OpenCV 3